# How to scale variables in a classical Hamiltonian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, scaling

So I looked at some research articles where one has a classical Hamiltonian $H(p,q,t) = p^{2}/2 + V(q,t)$. If one introduces the scaling transformation

$$t \mapsto t/\sqrt{s}, \quad H \mapsto Hs, \quad p\mapsto p\sqrt{s}, $$ and chooses $s = \epsilon ^{-2}$, the Hamiltonian writes as

$$\hat{H} = p^{2}/2 + \epsilon^{2}V(q,\epsilon t).$$

I don't understand how one arrives at this new Hamiltonian. I assume the new function $\hat{H}$ is written in terms of the new scaled variables, but even then I can't see how Hamilton's equations give the desired expression?

I would be grateful if one provides an explicit derivation of this result.

Answer (score -1):

The quality of the pic is not the best but i hope it helps
[image]

Comment: We have MathJax working on the site., so you shouldn't post pictures of hand-written equations. See  http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting and http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/ . Please.

Comment: Please do not post images of formulae, but use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset formulae.

Comment: Ok thanks. I assumed that the scaling transformation means we define the new variables $p_{1}=p\sqrt{s}$, $t_{1}=t/\sqrt{s},H_{1}=Hs$, and write $$H=H_{1}/s = p_{1}^{2}/2s + V(q,\sqrt{s}t_{1})$$... Then obviously $H_{1}$ has $1/\epsilon^{2}$ multiplying the potential, which is the opposite of what was required. Overthought the statement! @ Gabriel